# Contar quantas vezes um determinado valor aparece em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso escrever um código que crie uma lista com números que são inseridos pelo usuário (a quantidade de números é definida pelo próprio) e imprimir qual valor dessa lista é o maior e quantas vezes ele aparece. Parece que consegui a primeira parte mas estou tendo dificuldade em contar quantas vezes o maior valor aparece para também imprimi-lo.

```
lista = (input('Digite números inteiros:').split())
max_value = None

for num in lista:
    if (max_value is None or num > max_value):
        max_value = num

print(f'Os números digitados foram {lista} e seu maior valor é {max_value}.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No teu caso o input retorna um tipo literal, sua lista contera literais ['12','32'] precisa converter
para [12,32] sem aspas simples.

```
Foi Transposta a lista e convertida  em numero inteiro naturais

Essa situação utilizei o sort para ordernar a lista do menor ao maior
primeira posição é o menor ultima bem óbvio é o maior
e uma funcao que conta as repetições count()


em python um texto é um lista:
exemplo
```

> ```
> texto ="Ola Mundo"
> for txt in texto:
>    print(txt)
> ```

```
resultado  
O
l
a
 
M
u
n
d
o

pode acessar por posição
```

o input tem a entrada do tipo string, os numeros são todos leterais
converti para inteiro e ordenei e apenas peguei a posição 0 e a ultima [-1]

talvez seja isso o que procura?

```
lista = input('Digite números inteiros:').split() #literal


lista = [int(i) for i in lista]#transposta, numeros  naturais


lista.sort() #ordena do menor ao maior
   
minimo= lista[0]  #  primeira posicao ou min(lista)
maximo= lista[-1]  # ultima posicao max(lista)  

minimo_rep = lista.count(minimo) # do minino quantas vezes repetiu      
maximo_rep = lista.count(maximo) # fo maximo quantas vezes repetiu
   
   

print(f'Os números digitados foram {lista}')
print(f'e seu maior valor é {maximo} repetiu {maximo_rep}')
print(f'e o menor é {minimo} repetiu {minimo_rep}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente dessa forma, o processo está comentado:

```
# Recupera a entrada do usuário
numeros_str = input('Digite números inteiros:')

# Cria uma lista de strings
lista_str = numeros_str.split()

# Converte em uma lista de inteiros
lista = list(map(int, lista_str))

# Identifica o valor máximo da lista
max_value = max(lista)

# Conta as ocorrências desse valor na lista
count_max_value = lista.count(max_value)

print(f'Os números digitados foram {lista} e seu maior valor é {max_value}, que se repete {count_max_value} vezes.')
```